# how to reference plan variables in bamboo with my selenium webdriver(java) file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, bamboo

I have selenium driver script

```
this.browsername = System.getenv("browsername");
tags.add(this.browsername);
this.browserversion = System.getenv("browserversion");
tags.add(this.browserversion);
```

but when i add variables from task configuration with 'variable name', 'value' 
and execute the script , it returns `NULL`, no value is passed to above mentioned variables through bamboo.

Answer (score 0):

Bamboo adds "bamboo_" prefix to variables, try it. Or modify your java class and print all environment variables to see what is exported